# Can't understand an exercise concerning equivalence relations

Tags: elementary-set-theory

(Jech & Hrbacek, *Introduction to Set Theory*; Chapter 2, Exercise 5.10)

[image]

The last sentence in (b). What *equivalence relations* $E_{S}$, $E_{S_{1}}$, $E_{S_{2}}$is he talking about? They seem to have come out of the blue.

Comment: Any partition of a set defines an equivalence relation: $a\sim b$ if $a$ and $b$ are in the same element of the partition. Presumably $E_S$, $E_{S_1}$, and $E_{S_2}$ are the relations defined by those three partitions.

Comment: with 635 points, you are no longer a novice on this site and should know how to use MathJax.

Comment: @5xum: What should I have done with MathJax?

Comment: @Graduate Write the question.

Comment: See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: @900sit-upsaday: Is it a violation of the rules to upload a picture that contains math notation rather that copy everything from the picture in MathJax?

Comment: It's [discouraged](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/13677/). Which is why this question got downvoted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $S$ is a partition of a set $A$, the natural equivalence relation on $A$ associated with $S$ is $x \ E_S \ y$ if and only if $(\exists a \in S)(x \in a \wedge y \in a)$. In other words, $x$ is equivalent to $y$ if and only if $x$ and $y$ are in the same piece of the partition.

It should be noted that all equivalence relation on a set $A$ come in this way: If $E$ is an equivalence relation on $A$, then the equivalence classes of $E$ forms a partition of $A$.